# Laravel validator fails (one more time here)

Tags: laravel, validation

Sorry if this has similar Q&A on SO, but i cant ge´t any help from there.

I have a latest version fresh Laravel store practising project. Everithing seems to work ok, but in updating products.
---UPDATE---

My product controller update() code:

```
$rules=[
        'nombre'=>'required|max:50|unique:articulos,nombre,'.$articulo->id.',id',
        'color'=>'required|max:60',
        'descripcion'=>'required',
        'precio_compra'=>'required|lt:precio_venta',
        'precio_venta'=>'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()
        ->route('articulos.edit',['articulo'=>$articulo])
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
    }


    $change=Articulo::find($articulo->id);
    $change->nombre=$request->nombre;
    $change->descripcion=$request->descripcion;
    $change->color=$request->color;
    $change->precio_compra=$request->precio_compra;
    $change->precio_venta=$request->precio_venta;
    $change->envio_domicilio=$request->envio_domicilio;
    $change->stock=$request->stock;
    $change->observaciones=$request->observaciones;
    $change->save();

    return view('articulos.actualizado')->with(
        ['nombre'=>$change->nombre]
    );
```

Actually, tried the comments offered, but Dynamic class error jumps. Tried restarting IDE and that error dissapeared, but $errors matrix still returning nothing on alert.

^^UPDATE^^
The problem is, when I get to the validator, it seems to fail. Tryed surrounding it with dd but nothing happens (and so if I leave it as code sample, it redirects me to the product edit view, showing a blank $errors alert tag, iserted via blade ifs, that make me think not an empty array of $errors is being passed to view). Any way codre from dd seems not to work.

This my blade $errors snippet:

```
@if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors as $e)
                    <li><strong>{{ $e }}</strong></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

---UPDATE---
Bunch of codes
Model:

```
protected $table='articulos';
    protected $fillable=[
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'color',
        'precio_compra',
        'precio_venta',
        'envio_domicilio',
        'stock',
        'observaciones'
    ];
    protected $hidden=[];
```

Blade:

```
@extends('layouts.main-layout')
@section('title','Editar '.$articulo->nombre)
@section('content')
    <h1>Editar articulo</h1>
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors as $e)
                    <li><strong>{{ $e }}</strong></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{{ route('articulos.update',['articulo'=>$articulo]) }}" method="POST">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <legend>Editar artículo</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre del artículo </label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="{{  old('nombre')?:$articulo->nombre }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="color">Color del artículo </label>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="{{  old('color')?:$articulo->color }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="pcompra">Precio de compra del artículo </label>
                </div>
                <input type="number" name="pcompra" id="pcompra" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="{{  old('pcompra')?:$articulo->precio_compra }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="pventa">Precio de venta del artículo </label>
                </div>
                <input type="number" name="pventa" id="pventa" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="{{  old('pventa')?:$articulo->precio_venta }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="stock">Disponible del artículo </label>
                </div>
                <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" value="{{  old('stock')?:$articulo->stock }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Envío a domicilio
                </div>
                <span>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="envio_domicilio" value="N" checked>
                        <span>NO</span>
                    </label>
                </span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="envio_domicilio" value="S" {{ old('envio_domicilio')=='S'?'checked': (($articulo->envio_domicilio=='S')?'checked':'') }}>
                        <span>SÍ</span>
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label><br>
                </div>
                <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" class="form-control">{{ old('descripcion')?:$articulo->descripcion }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-12 special">
                    <label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                </div>
                <textarea name="observaciones" id="observaciones" class="form-control">{{ old('observaciones')?:$articulo->observaciones }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col-sm-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" value="Enviar">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col-sm-3">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary btn-small" value="Borrar">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Controller methods:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $reglas=[
            'nombre'=>'required|max:50|unique:articulos,nombre',
            'color'=>'required|max:60',
            'descripcion'=>'required',
            'pcompra'=>'required|lt:pventa',
            'pventa'=>'required'
        ];
        $request->validate($reglas);

        $nuevoArticulo=new Articulo;

        $nuevoArticulo->nombre=$request['nombre'];
        $nuevoArticulo->descripcion=$request['descripcion'];
        $nuevoArticulo->color=$request['color'];
        $nuevoArticulo->precio_compra=$request['pcompra'];
        $nuevoArticulo->precio_venta=$request['pventa'];
        $nuevoArticulo->envio_domicilio=$request['envio'];
        $nuevoArticulo->stock=$request['stock'];
        $nuevoArticulo->observaciones=$request['observaciones'];
        $nuevoArticulo->save();

        return view('articulos.grabado')->with(['articulo'=>$request['nombre']]);
    }

public function update(Request $request, Articulo $articulo)
    {
        $rules=[
            'nombre'=>'required|max:50|unique:articulos,nombre,'.$articulo->id.',id',
            'color'=>'required|max:60',
            'descripcion'=>'required',
            'precio_compra'=>'required|lt:precio_venta',
            'precio_venta'=>'required',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()
            ->route('articulos.edit',['articulo'=>$articulo])
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
        }


        dd($validator->errors());
        $change=Articulo::find($articulo->id);
        $change->nombre=$request->nombre;
        $change->descripcion=$request->descripcion;
        $change->color=$request->color;
        $change->precio_compra=$request->precio_compra;
        $change->precio_venta=$request->precio_venta;
        $change->envio_domicilio=$request->envio_domicilio;
        $change->stock=$request->stock;
        $change->observaciones=$request->observaciones;
        $change->save();

        return view('articulos.actualizado')->with(
            ['nombre'=>$change->nombre]
        );
    }
```

...from which store is working (validating and loading view correctly) and update is failing. Also migrations shouldn´t be the problem, as they are working properly on store method, and also Irechecked DB types and so, just in case...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call the `all()` method on the `$errors` object:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $e)
            <li><strong>{{ $e }}</strong></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

The reason you're not seeing anything from the `dd($v)` is because calling `validate()` on the `$request` object automatically redirects back to the requesting page if validation fails.

If you want more control over the validation flow, you can use the `Validation` facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    // your rules
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('go-somewhere')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

**Update**

So your blade view is still not using `$errors->all()` as I have mentioned previously.

If you want to `dd` errors in your controller, you need to use:

```
dd($validator->errors());
```

**Further update**

So the `dd($validator->errors())` is after `if ($validator->fails())` so it is never going to `die and dump` any errors because your code is redirecting back to the form with the validation errors and input. To `die and dump` the errors, you want to put that **inside** your conditional, but **only** for testing.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // dd($validator->errors());  <---- uncommet to see errors
    return redirect()
        ->route('articulos.edit',['articulo'=>$articulo])
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Again and as mentioned previously, you've not updated your blade code to use the `all()` method on the `$errors` object so none of your errors are being displayed even though they exist. Change your blade errors conditional to the following:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $e)  {{--  <----- $errors->all() --}}
            <li><strong>{{ $e }}</strong></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: tryed, but  the if part returns Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch. Also tried redirect()->route, but the problem is within if

Comment: Have you imported `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` at the top of your `ProductController`?

Comment: First thing I did, sorry

Comment: Will need to see your updated controller to be able to help further.

Comment: I dunno why... restarted IDE and dynamic class names errors, disappeared.  But now on starting point. Updated question

Comment: @VidalM. I've updated my answer based on your recent update.

Comment: sorry for not posting Controller with dd($validator->errors()), but it doesn´t return me any results, and ProductUpdateView is returned, showing the red alert empty

Comment: I really can't help without seeing the exact code you're running. Please update your question with **all** your current code.

Comment: Btw, Im new to laravel, but trying to get it as fast as I can, job matters. In this codes, they are extracted from a book, with slightest own (and now yours and SO too), but its written for previous versions of laravel than I'm using. Thanks to his author too

Comment: @VidalM. Added a further update. Please read carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much @Unflux , sorry for the inconveniences, just starting, and my english poor, Answer solved. Owe you a beer, or some water ^_^

Comment: @VidalM. It's all good, pleased you got it resolved!